# Play Framework - Platform restriction: a parameter list's length cannot exceed 254

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I have just updated a play framework application to 2.6 from 2.5.13

I have managed to follow the migration guides and get everything else up to scratch however I can't find a solution to the following error:

> Platform restriction: a parameter list's length cannot exceed 254.

My routes file is rather large however this was not a problem on the previous version.

I believe this error is a limitation put in by Play Framework to stop routes files from becoming too large however it seems rather pointless when the previous version allowed it.

I have also seen that you can split routes files using modules however that will not be possible for this case, ideally there should be a way without the overhead of completely rebuilding the app.

Is there a way to split routes files WITHOUT modules or a simple fix for this error?

Comment: Even if it was eventually accepted before, a so large parameter list seems a bad practice (compared to handling an appropriate body)

Comment: So having more than 254 URL's is too many? It seems like a very low number to me.

Comment: The error message mentions "parameter list", not route list for me

Comment: I’m confused as to what that means though, I just assumed it was routes as I have no clue where or what the parameter list is.

Comment: I suspect the problem here is not the number of routes, but the number of controllers. The generated router needs to have an instance of each controller and if you have too many of them, you will [reach a JVM limitation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11). Take a look at your `target/scala-2.12/routes/main/router/Routes.scala` and see the constructors there.

Comment: And, yes, [splitting the routes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/dxDRml0khdY/92Sf48Fhs4MJ) files is a possible solution.

Comment: Is there a way to split the routes file without creating modules? Every solution I’ve seen requires turning the app into sub projects which isn’t a possibility right now.

Comment: The article linked is one of the options i've tried already however it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question just in case anyone else experiences a similar issue as their Play app grows.

@marcospereira was right, there were too many routes for the generated router to handle.

You can successfully split the routes file WITHOUT the pain and overkill of creating modules.

As I already had packages set up for controllers in different parts of the app it was easy to create a `package.routes` file for each one.

Once the original routes file had been emptied into the relevant sub-routes files and URL's adjusted accordingly the application built successfully.

Something that may not be obvious to people doing this for the first time is that you need to make sure the that each routes file matches the package containing the controllers they are splitting.

For example if you have a package for admin controllers called `admin` you can create a routes file in your `/conf` folder called `admin.routes`.

> It must be packagename.routes.

File `/conf/routes`:

```
GET     /                       controllers.Home.index
->      /admin                  admin.Routes
->      /user                   user.Routes
```

File `/conf/admin.routes`:

```
GET    /                        controllers.admin.Admin.index
GET    /analytics               controllers.admin.Analytics.dashboard
```

File `/conf/user.routes`:

```
GET    /                        controllers.user.User.index
GET    /profile                 controllers.user.User.profile
```

> Important to remember that the GET / in each package.routes is equivalent to /package/ from the original routes file.